# Jekyll site data with dots in identifier

Tags: json, jekyll

Assume you have a JSON file `_data/test.json` with the following content

```
{"foo.bar":"42"}
```

and you want to query it in Jekyll/Liquid. A naive try would look like:

```
{{ site.data.test."foo.bar" }}
```

which does not work. Any idea how to look up "foo.bar"?

I'm using Jekyll 3.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the alternate syntax as well:

```
{{ site.data.test["foo.bar"] }}
```